# Graphics2D object always gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, graphics

I want to create simple drawing program;

Here I my program's mousePressed and mouseDragged events:

```
private void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    touch = evt.getPoint();
    pressed = true;
}


private void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Point p = evt.getPoint();
    if(pressed){
        graphics2D.drawLine(touch.x, touch.y, p.x, p.y);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

But when I try to draw someting, it always give `"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"`  in this line `graphics2D.drawLine(touch.x, touch.y, p.x, p.y);`

I also overrided the method paintComponent

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        clear();
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

And I the clear method is:

```
public void clear(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on how to draw stuff in Java:
[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)

If you're using Swing to do custom painting, you should override the method `paintComponent(Graphics g)` on the component for which you want to do custom painting for and do the painting inside that overriden method. You will always get an initialized `Graphics` object in that method.

Comment: I also overrided the paintComponent(Graphics g) method

Comment: @CanCeylan: You can't draw your line in the mouseDragged(...) method. That won't work. Store the points you get from the MouseEvent and do the line drawing in paintComponent(...).

Comment: but my starting point is this link: http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/31180-java-mini-paint-program.html. In that link I can draw lines in mouseDragged method. I want to apply this schema in my GUI

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not and you still need help, update your question with your complete code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified anything about `graphics2D`. My guess is that it's a field which you're never initializing, so it'll always have a null value.

You should probably actually be adding a line to some list of "lines to draw" and then actually doing the drawing part in a paint handler. That's the event to handle when you want to do any painting.

Comment: In which value should I initialize graphics2D ? I only wrote  Graphics2D graphics2D;

Comment: @CanCeylan: Right, so that's an instance variable which will indeed have a null default value. If you handle the paint event, you should be given the graphics to draw on *in that method*, as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code looks reasonable. You initialize the graphics2D variable when you create your image.

[Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) shows two ways to do this. One of the approaches is painting to a BufferedImage, which is similiar to what you are tying to do. Compare the code to see what is different.